# Use only php from xampp

Tags: 18.04, php, lamp, xampp

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` and `xampp` with `php 7.4`.

I am trying to change the `> php` path variable.

I tried:

```
admin@admin:/opt/lampp/bin$ sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
admin@admin:/opt/lampp/bin$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

As you can see my path variable seems to be under `/usr/bin/php`.

1. How can I check the current path variable of `php`?
2. How can I set `xampp's` php executable as `PATH` variable?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `/opt/lampp/bin/php` in the location `/usr/bin/php`. At the same time, this file is what is called when launching just `php` on the command line according to your `which` output.

> How can I check the current path variable of `php`?

To check the target of a symlink (likely) found using the `which` command, use `readlink -f` or `realpath`.

```
readlink -f $(which php)
```

or

```
realpath $(which php)
```

> How can I set xampp's `php` executable as `PATH` variable?

From what you claim to have done, you have set it already! However, to prevent potential conflicts with a `php` program installed by the Ubuntu’s package management system, you should rather create the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`. The `/usr/local/bin` directory should be in your `PATH` variable before `/usr/bin`. To check this, run:

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a point to note. You can just install XAMPP only without PHP from Ubuntu PAckage repo and create a symlink to avoid any multiple php conflicts like this

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```